# Deserialize XML to Class. Проблема десериализации одинаковых типов из одного пространства имен, но с элементами из разных пространств имен

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Есть XML-файл с 3мя пространствами имен: ns2="2020-04-02", ns3="2017-10-23", ns4="2017-10-08"
Есть 3 вариации блоков:
1 вариант

```
<ns3:ВыработкаКалендарная>
  <ns3:ВсеМесяцы>0</ns3:ВсеМесяцы>
  <ns3:ВсеДни>17</ns3:ВсеДни>
</ns3:ВыработкаКалендарная>
```

2 вариант

```
<ns2:ВыработкаКалендарная>
  <ns4:ВсеГоды>0</ns4:ВсеГоды>
  <ns4:ВсеМесяцы>3</ns4:ВсеМесяцы>
  <ns4:ВсеДни>14</ns4:ВсеДни>
</ns2:ВыработкаКалендарная>
```

3 вариант

```
<ns2:ВыработкаКалендарная>
  <ns3:ВсеМесяцы>6</ns3:ВсеМесяцы>
  <ns3:ВсеДни>20</ns3:ВсеДни>
</ns2:ВыработкаКалендарная>
```

Пробовал считывать таким кодом

```
[XmlElementAttribute("ВыработкаКалендарная", typeof(ТипВыработкаКалендарнаяДо2002), Namespace = "2020-04-02")]
[XmlElementAttribute("ВыработкаКалендарная", typeof(ТипВыработкаКалендарнаяДо2002ПослеРегистрации), Namespace = "2020-04-02")]
[XmlElementAttribute("ВыработкаКалендарная", typeof(ТипВыработкаКалендарная), Namespace = "2017-10-23")]
public object ВыработкаКалендарная
{
    get
    {
        return this._выработкаКалендарная;
    }
    set
    {
        this._выработкаКалендарная = value;
    }
}
```

Предварительно создал 3 класса

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "2017-10-23")]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "2017-10-23", IsNullable = false)]
public class ТипВыработкаКалендарная
{
    #region Private fields
    private string _всеГоды;
    private string _всеМесяцы;
    private string _всеДни;
    #endregion
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество месяцев
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true)]
    public string ВсеГоды
    {
        get
        {
            return _всеГоды;
        }
        set
        {
            _всеГоды = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеГоды
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеГоды, out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    public string ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеМесяцы;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеМесяцы = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеМесяцы, out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество дней
    /// </summary>
    public string ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеДни;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеДни = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеДни, out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Выработка календарная
/// </summary>
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "2020-04-02")]
public class ТипВыработкаКалендарнаяДо2002
{
    #region Private fields
    private object _всеГоды;
    private object _всеМесяцы;
    private object _всеДни;
    #endregion
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество месяцев
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "2017-10-08")]
    public object ВсеГоды
    {
        get
        {
            return _всеГоды;
        }
        set
        {
            _всеГоды = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеГоды
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеГоды.ToString(), out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "2017-10-08")]
    public object ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеМесяцы;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеМесяцы = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеМесяцы.ToString(), out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество дней
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "2017-10-08")]
    public object ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеДни;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеДни = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеДни.ToString(), out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Выработка календарная
/// </summary>
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "2020-04-02")]
public class ТипВыработкаКалендарнаяДо2002ПослеРегистрации
{
    #region Private fields
    private string _всеМесяцы;
    private string _всеДни;
    #endregion
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество месяцев
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "2017-10-23")]
    public string ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеМесяцы;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеМесяцы = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеМесяцы, out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество дней
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "2017-10-23")]
    public string ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеДни;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеДни = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеДни, out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Но при десериализации выдается сообщение об ошибке отражения типа.
Если оставить один из двух типов пространства имен ns2, то десериализация проходит без ошибок, но считывается только класс, который оставлен
Подскажите, как такое можно победить?

Comment: Обязательно использовать (де)сериализацию? Можно, например, с помощью linq to xml извлечь данные. И тут ещё вопрос: нужно ли сохранять сведения, из какого пространства имён пришли данные?

Comment: Я привел часть структуры. На самом деле там большая вложенность и эти тэги на самом нижнем уровне. Нужны все данные из файла. Поэтому linq to xml достаточно сложно использовать.
Сведения из какого пространства имен не нужны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге получилось прочитать сделав следующее: 2 класса из Namespace = "2020-04-02" заменил на один такой

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://пф.рф/СЗИ-НВП/2020-04-02")]
public class ТипВыработкаКалендарнаяДо2002
{
    #region Private fields
    private string _всеГоды;
    private string _всеМесяцы;
    private string _всеДни;
    private string _всеМесяцыП;
    private string _всеДниП;
    #endregion

    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "http://пф.рф/ВС/типы/2017-10-23")]
    public string ВсеМесяцыП
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеМесяцыП;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеМесяцыП = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество дней
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "http://пф.рф/ВС/типы/2017-10-23")]
    public string ВсеДниП
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеДниП;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеДниП = value.Trim();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Количество месяцев
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "http://пф.рф/ПУ/типы/2017-10-08")]
    public string ВсеГоды
    {
        get
        {
            return _всеГоды;
        }
        set
        {
            _всеГоды = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "http://пф.рф/ПУ/типы/2017-10-08")]
    public string ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеМесяцы;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеМесяцы = value.Trim();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Количество дней
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer", IsNullable = true, Namespace = "http://пф.рф/ПУ/типы/2017-10-08")]
    public string ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            return this._всеДни;
        }
        set
        {
            this._всеДни = value.Trim();
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеГоды
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            ushort.TryParse(this._всеГоды.ToString(), out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеМесяцы
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            if (!ushort.TryParse(this._всеМесяцы, out ret)) ushort.TryParse(this._всеМесяцыП, out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ushort _ВсеДни
    {
        get
        {
            ushort ret;
            if (!ushort.TryParse(this._всеДни, out ret)) ushort.TryParse(this._всеДниП, out ret);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

В интернете чет такого решения нигде не было.